# Problem referencing two JavaScript files within Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two Javascript files like below, a parent which defines a method and a child which calls the method from the parent:

**parent.js**

```
function HelloWorld() {
    alert('HelloWorld');
}
```

**child.js**

```
HelloWorld();
```

In my Angular component I am referencing the script like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import 'src/app/parent.js';
import 'src/app/child.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-dream-app';
}
```

When I run the application, I receive an error in the console stating:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWorld is not defined**

If I call HelloWorld() from within Parent.js it works fine; but it doesn't seem like Angular likes have two separate JS files.  When I do this in just a pure HTML file and include both scripts in the  this works just fine.  What am I missing about my Angular component that would prevent what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because typescript is compiling everything to closed annonymous functions. So your `parent.js` will be compiled to

```
(function(module, exports) {

function helloWorld () {
  console.log('hello')
}

/***/ }),
```

And you can't have access to that scope.

But if you do a `export function helloWorld() {...}` and then import it into `child.js` like:

***child.js***

```
import {helloWorld} from '../path/to/child.js'
helloWorld()
```

**OR**

```
import * as parent from './parent.js';
parent.helloWorld()
```

then child will have access to that function.